# Is $y=x$ an inclined asymptote of $f(x)=x+e^{-x}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, exponential-function

I actually thought that inclined asymptotes are only for the rational functions. But when i am trying to plot $f(x)=x+e^{-x}$, we can see that
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}y-x=0$$
So $y=x$ is an inclined asymptote.
So is there a formal approach to find inclined asymptote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking in wikipedia we have: "In analytic geometry, an asymptote of a curve is a line such that the distance between the curve and the line approaches zero as one or both of the x or y coordinates tends to infinity"

So an example when $mx+b$ is an asymptote of the graph of $f$ is $f(x)=mx+b+g(x)$ where $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}g(x) = 0$. (or $x\to -\infty$).

In our case our function is of that form. It is $x+e^{-x}$

Comment: Just now looked in to I.A.Maron's single variable calculus. He defines inclined asymptotes as: $\lim _{x \rightarrow+\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}=k_{1}, \quad \lim _{x \rightarrow+\infty}\left[f(x)-k_{1} x\right]=b_{1}$, then $y=k_1x+b_1$ is an inclined asymptote. I think this is the formal way to identify.

Comment: @Umeshshankar: That would be a strange way to **define** it. It's usually *derived* from the definition in the answer above, as the way to look for asymptotes in practice.

Answer (score 1):

An inclined asymptote is really just looking at the dominant part of the function for large/small/ particular values of $x$. so in this case if we look at large $x$:
$$x+e^{-x}\approx x$$
due to the rapidly decaying exponential. Another example of where they are used is functions like:
$$\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$$
which you will see has the sinusoidal behaviour but is also decaying due to the $1/x$ term. Since we can say:
$$-\frac{1}{x}\le\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\le \frac{1}{x}$$
these curves are often used to describe the behaviours of these functions. Hope this helps